# Mongo C# Driver: Deserialize BsonValue

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a document in mongodb that is structured similar to this:

```
{
  "_id": "abcdef01234",
  "Name": "Product A",
  "Dimensions": [
    {
      "Height": 32,
      "Width": 64
    },
    {
      "Height": 16,
      "Width": 32
    },
    {
      "Height": 8,
      "Width": 16
    }
  ]
}
```

I also have a class defined to represent dimensions (the sub document from above)

```
public class Dimension
{
  public int Height { get; set; }
  public int Width { get; set; }
}
```

I am selecting the "Product A" document in this manner:

```
MongoServer srv = MongoServer.Create(myConnStr);
BsonDocument doc = srv["db"]["products"].FindOneById(ObjectId.Parse("abcdef01234"));
BsonValue dimensionsVal = doc["Dimensions"];
```

Now I have a BsonValue named dimensionsVal which is of type BsonArray.  What I really want is a List<Dimension>. How do I convert dimensionsVal to a List<Dimension>?

**Edit**
The dimension class is actually significantly more complex than what I described. I want to keep the Dimensions separate from the Product because of memory concerns. I want to keep the Product in memory, but not the (potentially enormous) list of dimensions. For this reason, I don't want to have a List as a property of the Product class.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here is how it can be done:

```
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization;

MongoServer srv = MongoServer.Create(myConnStr);
BsonDocument doc = srv["db"]["products"].FindOneById(ObjectId.Parse("abcdef01234"));
BsonValue dimVal = doc["Dimensions"];
List<Dimension> d = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Dimension>>(dimVal.ToJson());
```

Comment: Just to explain to everyone what this code snippet does:   First the Value is converted to JSON, Once that happens it can easily be deserialized into any object

Answer (score 5):

**Update:**

You probably looking for [include/exclude](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields) functionality. In c# driver it done so:

```
 // load products without array of Dimensions
MongoCursorInstance.SetFields(Fields.Exclude("Dimensions"));
//load empty product with Dimensions and _id
MongoCursorInstance.SetFields(Fields.Include("Dimensions"));
```

---

Why not just create class for product? In this case driver will be able to deserialize data automatically :

```
class Product
{
   [BsonId]
   public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

   public string Name{ get; set; }

   public List<Dimension> Dimensions{ get; set; }

}

var product = srv["db"]["products"].FindOneByIdAs<Product>();
var dimentions = product.Dimensions;
```

But if you don't want create `Product` class you can go this way:

```
BsonArray dimensionsVal = doc["Dimensions"].AsBsonArray;

var list = new List<Dimension>();
foreach (BsonValue value in dimensionsVal)
{
  var bsonDoc = (BsonDocument) value;
  var d = new Dimension();
  d.Height = bsonDoc["Height"];
  d.Width = bsonDoc["Width"];
  list.Add(d);
}
```

Comment: I'm hoping a solution such as you propose is unnecessary, i.e. that there is a way to automatically deserialize the Dimensions into a list.  If not, I may add a constructor to the Dimension class that takes a BsonDocument as a parameter and manually populate the Dimension from the BsonDocument.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
public class Product
{
   [BsonId]
   public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

   public string Name{ get; set; }

   public List<DimensionDoc> Dimensions{ get; set; }
}

public class DimensionDoc
{
   public int Height { get; set; }
   public int Width { get; set; }

}

Product product = srv["db"]["products"].FindOneByIdAs<Product>(ObjectId.Parse("abcdef01234"));
```

product.Dimensions will now contain the List<> you need.

Comment: The dimension class is actually significantly more complex than what I described and includes a reference to another document.  I want to keep the Dimensions separate from the Product because of memory concerns. I want to keep the Product in memory, but not the dimensions. This is why I'm attempting to do it differently from what you describe.

Comment: Why don't you create another class that has all fields of the product but not the dimensions. Then once the document is loaded from db, just copy the fields to that object except the dimensions. Then you put that object in memory. Is your list of dimenions are too big that may take too much memory?

Answer (score 1):

I would declare your class with a Dimensions property of type List<Dimension> as others have proposed. Then if you want to read a Product *without* the Dimensions values write this:

```
ObjectId productId;
var query = Query.EQ("_id", productId);
var fields = Fields.Exclude("Dimensions");
var product = collection.Find(query).SetFields(fields).FirstOrDefault();
// product.Dimensions will be null because there was no data for it
```

and when you want to read the full product *including* all of the Dimensions write this:

```
ObjectId productId;
var query = Query.EQ("_id", productId);
var product = collection.FindOne(query);
// product.Dimensions will be populated this time
```

This will be much more efficient than reading the Dimensions into a BsonDocument and converting them to a List<Dimension> with hand-written code. That approach results in two copies of the data being loaded in memory (although presumably the BsonDocument version will be garbage collected soon thereafter if you don't keep a reference to it).